# Where to get the hammer suit

Tags: super-mario-bros-3

> The hammer suit is a suit where you can act like a Hammer Bros.

In various gameplay, I have seen the hammer suit in use,  but doesn't state where to get it.  Where are they found?

Answer (score 4):

According to this [Super Mario Bros 3 Guide](http://toadscastle.net/super-mario-bros-3-guide/) there are five locations in the game where you can obtain the Hammer Suit.

- Mushroom house two in world 6 gives you a hammer suit.
- World 6-10 has a hidden hammer suit in it.

> Hit the second normal block above the white block and climb up the vine. Jump onto the platform, the last block contains a P-Switch. Once it’s hit you could jump to the right and collect some coins. Move quickly to the pipe covered in frozen Munchers. Melt them with fire and they will become coins. Go down the pipe to find a huge Question block holding a Hammer Suit.

- Mushroom house two and three in world 7 have a chance to drop a hammer suit along with a chance for a tanooki suit and frog suit.
- The last location is in world 7-8.

> When you get to the second Ptooie go down the first pipe to discover a huge Question Block containing a Hammer Suit.

Answer (score 0):

In world 2 before you choose to play level 4 or 5, there are two hammer bros on the map. There is a chance to spawn a hammer suit if you face the hammer bro protecting level 5.

Answer (score -1):

There is a red mushroom house in world 6 that is full of hammer suits
To get to the red mushroom house use the pipe and destroy the dirt.
Another way is to complete either courses 2 or 3.